# Classic ASP and Paypal API SOAP

Tags: asp-classic, paypal

Im trying to call de GetVerifiedStatus API.
Im using a server with Windows 7.
Can anyone help me plz.
This is my code:

```
Dim objXMLHTTP : set objXMLHTTP = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0")
Dim strRequest, strResult, strURL

strURL = "https://svcs.paypal.com/AdaptiveAccounts/GetVerifiedStatus"

strRequest ="<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>" _
& "<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/""          xmlns:SOAP-ENC=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/""" _
& "        xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance""    xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"">" _
& "    <SOAP-ENV:Header>" _
& "         <RequesterCredentials xmlns=""urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI""     xsi:type=""ebl:CustomSecurityHeaderType"">" _
& "         <Credentials xmlns=""urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents""    xsi:type=""ebl:UserIdPasswordType"">" _
& "              <Username>XXXX</Username>" _
& "              <Password>XXXX</Password>" _
& "              <Signature>XXXX</Signature>" _
& "              <Subject>XXXX</Subject>" _
& "         </Credentials>" _
& "         </RequesterCredentials>" _
& "     </SOAP-ENV:Header>" _
& "     <SOAP-ENV:Body>" _

& "                 <Version xmlns=""urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents"">98.0</Version>" _
& "                 <emailAddress xs:""string"">john@gmail.com</emailAddress>" _
& "                 <firstName xs:""string"">John</firstName>" _
& "                 <lastName xs:""string"">Vegas</lastName>" _
& "                 <matchCriteria xs:""string"">NAME</matchCriteria>" _
& "                 <requestEnvelope common:""RequestEnvelope"">" _
& "                     <detailLevel xs:""string"">ReturnAll</detailLevel>" _
& "                     <errorLanguage xs:""string"">en_US</errorLanguage>" _
& "                 </requestEnvelope>" _

& "     </SOAP-ENV:Body>" _
& "</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>"

objXMLHTTP.open "post", "" & strURL & "", False

objXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8"
objXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Length", Len(strRequest)

objXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", strURL

objXMLHTTP.send(strRequest)
strResult = objXMLHTTP.responseText

response.write strResult
```

Im receiving this error:

```
msxml3.dll erro '800c0008'

Failed to download the specified resource
```

At objXMLHTTP.send(strRequest) line.
When I changed my http object to MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP, returns a error that said:
A certified is necessary to complete the client authentication.

Tks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Call objXMLHTTP.send(strRequest) instead of objXMLHTTP.send(strRequest)

I am not sure but you can try this because i found this from Classic ASP tutorial for payment gatway.

Here is the link for that: http://jadendreamer.wordpress.com/2009/09/02/classic-asp-soap-request-code-example